# Python - replace and insert in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, insert

Say I have a list:

```
lst = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

I would want to replace the `3` with `[5,6,7]`, so I get

```
lst = [1,2,5,6,7,4]
```

I tried:

```
lst[2] = [5,6,7]
```

but this will give me an error:
`setting an array element with a sequence`

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the size of a numpy array in-place.  You'll need to "manually" create a new numpy array of the appropriate size by concatenating slices of your other two arrays:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y = np.concatenate((x[:2], [5, 6, 7], x[3:]))
>>> y
array([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4])
```

Alternatively, you could convert your array to a list and do the replacement on the list:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y[2:3] = [5, 6, 7]
>>> y = np.array(y)
>>> y
array([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4])
```

(Note that unlike an operation such as `x[2] = 3`, both of these options create a new independent array, rather than mutating `x`.)

Numpy arrays are not compatible with size-changing operations; the only way to do it is to make an entirely new array.  If you need to change the size of objects, don't use numpy arrays; if you need to use numpy arrays, find a way to minimize or avoid changing their sizes.